# Closures in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it ok use closures in react, for event handlers?
For example, i have some function and a lot of menu in navigation
and in navigation component i use something like this:

```
handleMenuClick(path) {
  return () => router.goTo(path)
}
... 
<MenuItem
  handleTouchTap={this.handleMenuClick('/home')}
>
```

or i should prefer just arrow function?

```
<MenuItem
  handleTouchTap={() => router.goTo('/home')}
>
```

first variant really make code cleaner, but i'm worried about performance with a large number of such elements

Comment: I don't agree that the first one is cleaner, and both versions will have similar performance. You'll be fine. Keep coding and carry on

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both should be avoided.

While they'll both work, they both have the same weakness that they'll cause unnecessary renders because the function is being created dynamically, and will thus present as a different object.

Instead of either of those, you want to create your functions in a static way and then pass them in. For something like your `MenuItem`, it should just get the string for the path and then have the code to do the routing inside. If it needs the router, you should pass that in instead.

The function should then be a pre-`bind`-ed function (usually in the constructor) and just passed in.

```
export class MenuItem extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      this.handleClick = () => this.props.router.go(this.props.path);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <Button onClick={ this.handleClick }>Go to link</Button>
      );
    }
}
```

You can use an arrow function in the constructor. That way it isn't recreated every render function, and thus you avoid unnecessary renders. That pattern works well for single-line simple functions. For more complex functions, you can also create them as a separate function, then `bind` it in the constructor.

```
export class MenuItem extends React.Component {
  handleClick() {
    this.props.router.go(this.props.path);
  }

  constructor() {
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  render() { /* same as above */ }
}
```

The point of this is that the handler is the same function every time. If it was different (which both methods you describe above would be), then React would do unnecessary re-renders of the object because it would be a different function every time.

Here are two articles which go into more details:

- https://ryanfunduk.com/articles/never-bind-in-render/
- https://daveceddia.com/avoid-bind-when-passing-props/

Comment: hm, but author of following article give us recomendation, to use closueres, where it needed? I know, we create new object here, when use closure, but this is give us so much space to use. I'm very simplify my example, in this function i can use whatever want - manipulate current menu state with path, etc

Comment: Keep reading the article. They go through a few things, but they mention arrow functions aren't perfect. The main point is that your handlers should not be created in the render function. They should be created in the constructor. You could create multiple handlers in the constructor of `<MenuItem>`'s parent, like 'this.handleClickHome = () => this.props.router.go('/home')`, but you don't want to create it in the render function.

Comment: but... in final code in this article author use { this.handleKeyPress(item) } in renderItem() method, so for each item in render() function is created own handler function, with closure) But I got ur opinion, thanks

Comment: Apparently I didn't read the article far enough. =p I don't recommend them doing that. Let me find a better example. The code they show would cause unnecessary renders because of binding in the render function.

Comment: @vanless I linked to two different articles which do it right. The second shows all the different ways and indicates which are good or bad.

Comment: The first article is delicious! Fully put everything in the shelves in my head. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

when you define a new method inside a react component (Object) as we know functions are object in javascript.

```
 let reactComponent={
addition: function(){ //some task ...},
render: function(){},
componentWillMount : function(){},
}
```

so, every new method should be bind with in the object using bind, but render() is already defined so we don't do

```
this.render = this.render.bind(this)
```

for each  new function, except react lifecycle methods are needed to be added and hence, we call the object (constructor function) methods using this.method().

Comment: If we use es6 with `class` syntax, don't need to use `bind()` method at all. But the question isn't about this :)