# React Function Components with hooks vs Class Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

With the introduction of [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) in React, the main confusion now is when to use function components with hooks and class components because with the help of hooks one can get `state` and partial `lifecycle hooks` even in function components. So, I have the following questions

- What is the real advantages of hooks?
- When to use function components with hooks vs Class components?

For example, function components with hooks can't help in perf as class components does. They can't skip re-renders as they don't have `shouldComponentUpdate` implemented. Is there anymore reasons?

Comment: *partial lifecycle hooks* where did you get this? I just gave a quick look on the reference link and it does not say about lifecycle methods. As far as my knowledge goes, most people chooses to use class components because they need access to state, not knowing the fact that it will add meta for lifecycle method. With hooks, you should have a functional component that has state minus the overhead of lifecycle method.

Comment: You should check [Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#%EF%B8%8F-effect-hook). This is more like componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount.

Comment: *useEffect, adds the ability to perform side effects from a function component. It serves the same purpose as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount in React classes, but unified into a single API*, so you do not have access to any lifecycle method. Its a wrapper that acts like one but you cannot access them individually.

Comment: A summary on class components limitations: https://www.basefactor.com/react-class-components-pitfalls (this management, hard to extract functionallity, managing related concerns in separated handlers, high order component usage noise, error prone process toggling from class component to functional and the other way around, learning to approached, classes and function based components).

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The idea behind introducing `Hooks` and other features like `React.memo` and `React.lazy` is to help reduce the code that one has to write and also aggregate similar actions together.

The docs mention few really good reason to make use of Hooks instead of classes

**It’s hard to reuse stateful logic between components** Generally when you use HOC or renderProps you have to restructure your App with multiple hierarchies when you try to see it in DevTools, Hooks avoid such scenarios and help in clearer code

**Complex components become hard to understand** Often with classes Mutually unrelated code often ends up together or related code tends to be split apart, it becomes more and more difficult to maintain. An example of such a case is event listeners, where you add listeners in `componentDidMount` and remove them in `componentWillUnmount` . Hooks let you combine these two

**Classes confuse both people and machines** With classes you need to understand binding and the context in which functions are called, which often becomes confusion.

> function components with hooks can't help in perf as class
> components does. They can't skip re-renders as they don't have
> shouldComponentUpdate implemented.

Function component can be memoized in a similar way as `React.PureComponent` with Classes by making use of `React.memo` and you can pass in a comparator function as the second argument to `React.memo` that lets you implement a custom comparator

---

The idea is to be able write the code that you can write using React class component using function component with the help of `Hooks` and other utilities. Hooks can cover all use cases for classes while providing more flexibility in extracting, testing, and reusing code.

Since hooks is not yet fully shipped, its advised to not use hooks for critical components and start with relatively small component, and yes you can completely replace classes with function components

---

However one reason that you should still go for Class components over the function components with hooks until Suspense is out for data fetching. Data fetching with useEffect hooks isn't as intuitive as it is with lifecycle methods.

Also @DanAbramov in one of his tweets mentioned that hooks are designed to work with Suspense and until suspense is out it's better to use Class

Comment: On that last note, there's some examples of AJAX requests with hooks in this recent question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53059059/react-hooks-making-an-ajax-request), if anyone is wondering how it can be done

Comment: @horyd, sure we can make use of useEffect to make API calls, but they may get messy. And I in my answer have mentioned the same

Comment: Are hooked components automatically memoized or is react.memo still needed for this?

Comment: @JoelHarkes Hooked components aren't memoized by default, you would need tou se React.memo to do that

Comment: Hi, I am a bit worried about the use of closures with hooks. Stateless components does not allow to handle parameters biding in a performant way. See this question for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45041878/closures-in-react. How is this solved with Hooks? By memoizing the closure?

Comment: @EricBurel You can use `useCallback` hook to memoize the handler. PLease check this post and let me know if you still need help

Comment: @pietrovismara  Well thats true, but that is being mentioned in the react docs which I quoted in my answer

Answer (score 7):

Hooks greatly reduce the amount of code you need to write and increase its readability.

It is worth noting though that there are hidden processes going on behind (Just like component did mount etc.) that mean if you don't understand what is going on it can be difficult to troubleshoot. It is best to experiment with them and read through the docs fully before implementing on a live project.

Also there is still limited support/documentation for testing hooks compared to classes.
https://dev.to/theactualgivens/testing-react-hook-state-changes-2oga

**Update 28/08/2020**
Use the react hooks testing library with custom hooks for testing
https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library

Answer (score 7):

Officially it sounds like **hooks will completely replace classes??** maybe one day, but think about it; hooks have been around for 3 years (as of Mar 2021), and there are pros and cons in adopting them (More pros than cons... don't get me wrong)

I have plenty more experience myself with state management/classes and after doing a lot of research and testing, **I found out that we need to know both classes and hooks very well.** Hooks require a fraction of the code for simple components and seem excellent for optimizing HOCs. Meanwhile classes seem better with routing, container components and asynchronous programming for example.

I'm sure there are plenty more cases where each technology is better, but my point is that **programmers need know both hooks and classes very well specially when working on projects with 100,000+ lines of code and millions of users**. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60134353/11239755