# React TypeError: "_this2.setState is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I know this question is getting asked a lot and I did check most of the other answers provided but I still can't find out why I get this error.

**Situation:**

I have my `textinput` class in which I have a simple form for the user to input a name. When the user submits the button a REST call to my backend is called and the UI should show the user's name.

I have overridden the function `componentDidMount` of my `App` class to have an initial call to my backend when the page is loaded. This call works and I get the correct answer from my backend and the UI gets updated.

But when i make the call from my `TextInput` class, I get the error:

> this2.setState is not a function

I believe that this is happening because I call the function from another class and the `this state` is not set correctly. I tried to bind all the things but that did not change anything. If anyone has an idea of what I am doing wrong, it would be very helpful!

I have the following classes:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import Greeting from './components/greeting';
import TextInput from './components/textInput';
import './App.css';

const axios = require('axios');

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {name: "World"};
    this.getFormattedNameFromBackend.bind(this);
    this.setState.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getFormattedNameFromBackend(this.state.name);
  }

  getFormattedNameFromBackend(name) {
    axios({
      method:'get',
      url:'http://localhost:8080/hello?name=' + name
    }).then((response) => {
      this.setState({ name : response.data.name});
    }).catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <Greeting data={this.state}/>
          <TextInput callBack = {this.getFormattedNameFromBackend}/>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

This is the main class where I get the error in the axios rest call.

the second class is this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class TextInput extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {value: ''};

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
      this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
      this.props.callBack(this.state.value);

      event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <form onSubmit= {this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Name:
            <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      );
    }
  }
```

so the Question is, how do i call the correct this in the method getFormattedNameFromBackend?

**Solved:**

the mistake was setting the props of the Textinputfield wrong. Correctly it should be

```
<TextInput callBack = {(name)=>this.getFormattedNameFromBackend(name)}/>
```

Comment: Sounds like `this` is referencing the wrong object.
Try printing what `this` is where it raises, or reading
this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45041878/closures-in-react

In short, events in render function act on `event` objects and not on the class that the render function is defined on, that is because events are async...

Comment: at the time i get the error "this" is an object of type textinput. But how to i change that?

Comment: Try looking at the link I provided, easiest way would be to bind it via closure
`onSubmit= (e) => {this.handleSubmit(e)}`. 
Take a look at this as well : https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: i am trying this but that actually gives me syntax errors. :/ I am trying this now: onSubmit={(e)=>this.handleSubmit(e)} but that gives me the same error i had before

Comment: take a look at this, it seems to be working https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/233958/

Comment: thank you so so much, the error was "<TextInput callBack = {(name)=>this.getFormattedNameFromBackend(name)}/>" i was looking in the wrong direktion TT. You helped me out alot thank you

Comment: Added an answer for others wondering about this. feel free to mark it as resolved!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anyone else reaches this question, https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html explains quite well why this happens.

In short, `this` is not bound when event callbacks are invoked.

The easiest way to fix this is by enclosing this :
`onSubmit={(e) => {this.handleSubmit(e)}` (altough this does create a new function instance each time, so need to be careful when using this method).

Answer (score 0):

The way you solved it works by simply avoiding the binding if `this` altogether, but your original problem was that the line

```
    this.getFormattedNameFromBackend.bind(this);
```

doesn't do exactly what you think it does.
`.bind()` returns a new function that wraps the original function, but you're not doing anything with that new function. `.bind()` doesn't modify the original function so `this.getFormattedNameFromBackend` remains unbound and that's why `<TextInput callBack = {this.getFormattedNameFromBackend}/>` didn't work.

If you had written that line as:

```
    this.getFormattedNameFromBackend = this.getFormattedNameFromBackend.bind(this);
```

...(like you do in your `TextInput` class) it would get bound properly and `callBack = {this.getFormattedNameFromBackend}` would work.

Like I said, by writing it as `callBack = {() => this.getFormattedNameFromBackend()}` you're avoiding the binding issue anyway so you can simply remove `this.getFormattedNameFromBackend.bind(this);` (and BTW, `this.setState.bind(this);` is pretty pointless too)